# Saving page preference in site navigation using SiteMapPath control

Tags: sitemappath

I have created site navigation in my ASP.net application using SiteMapPath control and its working fine. Now my requirement is that, there is open page in my application which has Radio buttons and based on their selection datagrid is populated from database. I want to save the radio  button selection in navigation url so that when I click on that page through navigation url then page will display the data from my selected options.
Any help would be highly appriciated.
Thanks,
Yogesh

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand. I propose some other solution (using `Session`). Add event to `radioButton` `onSelectionChange`. When selection change, remember this in `Session`

```
 Session["name_param"] = some_params;
```

And in form with dataGrid get event PageLoad with code:

```
 if ( Session["name_param"] != null ) {
       var param = Session["name_param"];
      // using param to load data to grid
 } else {
      // something else, maybe default chance for data to grid
 }
```